# Does the SEC require an announcement of hostile takeovers?

Tags: united-states, stocks, regulation, sec

Elon Musk bought 9% (or so) of Twitter. Apparently he failed to make some sort of disclosure, which [he is being sued for](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2022/04/lawsuit-musk-saved-143-million-by-illegally-waiting-to-disclose-twitter-stake/)

> Musk started buying Twitter stock in January and acquired more than 5 percent of all shares by March 14, the lawsuit said. Under US law, "Musk was required to file a Schedule 13 with the SEC within 10 days of passing the 5 percent ownership threshold in Twitter, or March 24, 2022," said the [complaint](https://storage.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.nysd.578187/gov.uscourts.nysd.578187.1.0_1.pdf) filed yesterday in US District Court for the Southern District of New York.

Ignoring the 10 vs 11 day wait, I have a broader question here. If the SEC requires such disclosure of buying more than 5%, does that not preclude quietly buying all the shares you can in a bid to take over the company? In other words, do you have to announce your intent to buy a controlling interest in the company ([as Elon Musk later did](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2022/04/elon-musk-offers-to-buy-100-of-twitter-for-43-billion/)) before you actually try?

Comment: That may be considered insider trading, since he'd be acting on material non-public information.